# conda install fails, conda info package

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am on windows using Anaconda with python 2.7, I want to install tensorflow,But when I try to install it by:

```
conda install tensorflow
```

I got error message:

```
 Solving environment: -Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nesri\Anaconda2\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\nesri\Anaconda2\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nesri\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 342, in _start_spinning
    self.fh.write('\b' * self._indicator_length)
  File "C:\Users\nesri\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 40, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "C:\Users\nesri\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 141, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "C:\Users\nesri\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 169, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
  File "C:\Users\nesri\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 174, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
IOError: [Errno 0] Error

failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - ipaddress
  - tensorflow
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

so what should i do ??

Comment: Have you installed `ipaddress` pinned to a specific version?

Comment: no i didn't how can i install it ?

Comment: No, you don't want to do that. I was asking because if you _had_ done that, it would be the obvious cause of your problem. Since you haven't done that, don't worry about that issue.

Comment: So, the next obvious thing to try is exactly what the error message says to try: run `conda info ipaddress` and `conda info tensorflow` and look for what conflicts. If you can't see the problem yourself, then edit the results into your question, because nobody else can debug it without that information.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new environment specifically for running tensorflow.

```
conda create --name tf python=2.7 jupyter tensorflow
```

The creation process will take some time, but after the installation, you can activate the new environment using

```
activate tf
```

Comment: yes i created a new environment but i stil have this message error

Answer (score 0):

run this command

```
conda create -n tfpy27 -c conda-forge python=2 tensorflow
```

or refer to this issue.
https://github.com/conda-forge/tensorflow-feedstock/issues/37